# What happened to Kakashi's Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

After Madara warped out of the Kamui dimension, what happened to Kakashi's sharingan? Did Madara destroy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it was implanted back to Obito, it's seen when they warp back out, Obito's left eye is back to be his Mangekyo (the eye the Black Zetsu part of him has).